# Error: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to store the result of checked checkboxes in local storage but when I try to save I get the error mentioned above.

Not quite sure what is undefined since I see the property in my code. 
Here's the code:

```
var getCheckboxValue = function (){
    var checkboxes = document.forms[0].features;
    for(var i=0, j=checkboxes.length; i<j; i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
        console.log(checkboxes[i].value);
            //featuresValue = $("features").value();
        }else{
            checkboxes = "No"
        }
        }
    }

var storeData = function (){
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000001);
    //getSelectedRadio();
    getCheckboxValue();
    var item = {};
        item.brand = ["Brand",$("brand").value];
        item.model = ["Model",$("model").value];
        item.comments = ["comments",$("comments").value];
        //item.acoustic = ["acoustic", acousticValue]; 
        item.features = ["features",checkboxes];

    //Save data into local storage: Use Stringify to convert our object to a string
    localStorage.setItem(id,JSON.stringify(item));
    alert("Contact Saved!");
}


//set link & submit click events
var save = $("button");
save.addEventListener("click", storeData);
```

and here's the relevant html:

```
<li>Features:
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"  name="features" value = "Cutaway" id="cutaway" /><label for="cutaway">Cutaway</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"  name="features" value = "Finished" id="finished" /><label for="finished">Finished</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"  name="features" value = "Inlay" id="inlay" /><label for="inlay">Inlay</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"  name="features" value = "Wide Neck" id="wneck" /><label for="wneck">Wide Neck</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"  name="features" value = "Left-handed" id="lhanded" /><label for="lhanded">Left-handed</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Alternatively, here's a link to the full code on github:

https://github.com/b80266/VFW-Project-2/blob/master/additem.html

https://github.com/b80266/VFW-Project-2/blob/master/main.js

Comment: What line is this coming from? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: @GolezTrol Why would `checkboxes[i]` be `undefined` though?

Comment: sorry the error is where it says "if(checkboxes[i].checked){"

Comment: @GolezTrol sorry. I did update my post to include the whole code.

Comment: A working (or not working in this case) http://jsfiddle.net example would be awesome.

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem (it seems): http://jsfiddle.net/jmUXY/

Comment: @GolezTrol I know and understand that, I would hope they understood that. The point of the question is **why** it's undefined...you were basically just repeating the title...

Comment: @Ian beat me to it:) Here's the full code if anyone's interested:
http://jsfiddle.net/2BQAW/

Comment: @GolezTrol Sorry, you definitely didn't offend me or anything like that. It definitely helped narrow down the problem to one line, I think I shouldn't have said anything, as your comment was better than no one saying anything

Comment: @Ian Good. :) But I've deleted my comments, because this discussion didn't add much, especially since your nice find of the problem. So I suggest you do the same, otherwise it looks silly. ;) I will delete this one later as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're overwriting the value of `checkboxes` (the original collection of checkboxes in the form) here:

```
}else{
    checkboxes = "No"
}
```

This is **inside** of the loop...the loop that is iterating through `checkboxes`. It is now iterating over the characters in the string "No", not the collection of elements you originally retrieved. This string is only 2 characters long, while your original loop has a cached value of `checkboxes.length` (5 elements) stored in `j` which is not updated each iteration, meaning it will loop past `i = 1`, accessing the third, fourth and fifth indexes, which are now undefined.

Another "problem", is that in your `storeData` function, you're calling `getCheckboxValue` but not storing it anywhere...then later you're referencing some `checkboxes` variable later - `item.features = ["features",checkboxes];`. You need to store the result, then use that variable. Here's a demo that seems to work with some assuming HTML:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var getCheckboxValue = function () {
    var checkboxes = document.forms[0].features;
    for (var i = 0, j = checkboxes.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            console.log(checkboxes[i].value + " is checked");
        } else {
            //checkboxes = "No";
            console.log(checkboxes[i].value + " is not checked");
        }
    }
};

var storeData = function () {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000001);
    var checkedBoxes = getCheckboxValue();
    var item = {};
    item.brand = ["Brand",$("brand").value];
    item.model = ["Model",$("model").value];
    item.comments = ["comments",$("comments").value];
    item.features = ["features",checkedBoxes];

    //Save data into local storage: Use Stringify to convert our object to a string
    localStorage.setItem(id,JSON.stringify(item));
    alert("Contact Saved!");
};


//set link & submit click events
var save = $("button");
save.addEventListener("click", storeData, false);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jmUXY/1/

Comment: +1 Completely missed that, good catch. I was trying to figure out why `checkboxes[1]` was `"o"` in the debugger... now I know.  I would consider rephrasing to "iterating over the characters in this string" as that's a bit more clear as to what's happening.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks :) And good point, I'll edit to explain that better! I just wanted to get this posted

Comment: ah! sorry new at javascript here. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenP. No problem, minor mistake. That's what StackOverflow is here for :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ian's suggestions, you can check all radios in any number of forms. See exemple:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
   //Do stuff
   //console.log("foi clicado");
   var marcados = 0;
   var naoMarcados = 0;
   //conta numero de checados
   var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type == "radio" && inputElems[i].checked === true) {
     count++;
     marcados = count;
    } else {
     naoMarcados = naoMarcados + 1;
    }
   }
   $("#marcados").html("Total de Marcados: " + marcados);
   $("#naomarcados").html("Total de Não Marcados: " + naoMarcados);

  }
 });
});
```

```html
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <p>
  FORM 1
  </p>
 <form id="1">
 <input type="radio">Em grau muito alto
  <input type="radio">Em grau alto
   <input type="radio">Em grau médio 
  <input type="radio" CHECKED>Em grau baixo
  <input type="radio">Em grau muito baixo
  <input type="radio">Não observo
  </form>
  <hr>

  <p>
  FORM 2
  </p>
  <form id="2">
 <input type="radio">Em grau muito alto
  <input type="radio">Em grau alto
   <input type="radio">Em grau médio 
  <input type="radio">Em grau baixo
  <input type="radio">Em grau muito baixo
  <input type="radio">Não observo
  </form>
  <hr>
  <div id="marcados"></div>
  <div id="naomarcados"></div>
```